# Radioactivity module. "how-to" most popular article in one day questions

Tags: 7, nodes

thanks for the time to read this question.

to me not is clear the concept of Radiactivity measures. how to get the most popular article in one day? I must use the half-life in 43200 seconds (12 hours)? when change this results? (each day in this case?), what's happen if I Cut-off energy to 0?. where is stored this results if I want a report per days?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According comparison of the Radioactivity results and a Analytics service, seems that 12 hours (in seconds) is the time needed to track 1 day.